# Setting Meteor user roles in fixtures not working

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, user-roles

I have a Meteor application with the following fixtures code:

**/imports/startup/server/fixtures.js**

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base'

if(Meteor.users.find().count === 0) {
    const users = [
        {username: "admin", email: "admin@testing.demo", profile: { name: "Admin" }, roles: ["admin"]},
        {username: "school", email: "school@testing.demo", profile: { name: "School Name" }, roles: ["school"]},
        {username: "teacher", email: "teacher@testing.demo", profile: { name: "Teacher" }, roles:["teacher"]}
    ]

    for(let user of users) {
        Accounts.createUser({
            username: user.username,
            email: user.email,
            password: "123456",
            profile: {
                name: user.profile.name,
            },
            roles: user.roles
        })
    }
}
```

On starting up my project all the accounts are created successfully except none of them have the roles field. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is that you pass options into the function that are not accepted by it. `createUser options` only accepts `username`, `email`, `password` and `profile`. You should study the [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-createUser), meteors API is very well documented.

Now, to set the user roles you have a couple of options, one of them would be use the `_id` of the newly created user, which is returned by `createUser` and then set the roles like so:

```
const userId = Accounts.createUser({
        username: user.username,
        email: user.email,
        password: "123456",
        profile: {
            name: user.profile.name,
        });
Roles.addUsersToRoles(userId, user.roles)
```

assuming that this is server side code. On the client this won't work. You could also set the roles directly using a `Meteor.users.update();` call or fiddle around with `Accounts.onCreateUser` callback, which is very nice for manipulating everything that you pass into `createUser`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you :)  Saved me a lot of time figuring it out